# Creating a bit mask for relevant bits over multiple bytes programmatically

Tags: c#, bit, bitmask

I'm working with a very long binary string that contains "fields" that can be everything from 2 to 32 bits long. So in some cases a "field" can span over multiple uneven bytes.

I managed to read out all the data but now I'm working editing and switching out data. Here is a current working example on a field that is 12 bits and start on a whole byte:

```
public class CardSectionProperty
{
    public CardSectionProperty(CardDataContainer data, MapItem mapItem)
    {
        Data = data;
        Start = mapItem.Position;
        Length = mapItem.Length;
    }

    public CardDataContainer Data { get; } // A simple container for the binary string of the whole card.

    public int Start { get; }

    public int Length { get; }

    public void SetValue(long value)
    {
        var relevantBits= 0xFF0F; // <- I think this mask need to change depending on the field size and position in the binary string.
        var newValue = (int)value;
        var oldValue = (int)GetValue();
        var bitsToKeep = (~relevantBits) & oldValue;
        var newValueCorrected = Switch16BitEndianness(newValue) | bitsToKeep;
        SetValue(Convert.ToString(newValueCorrected, 2));
    }

    private void SetValue(string binaryValue)
    {
        var builder = new StringBuilder(Data.BinaryData);
        builder.Remove(Start, binaryValue.Length);
        builder.Insert(Start, binaryValue);
        Data.BinaryData = builder.ToString();
    }

    private int Switch16BitEndianness(int x)
    {
        return ((x & 0xFF00) >> 8) | ((x & 0x00FF) << 8);
    }
}
```

Here the mask is 0xFF0F (1111 1111 0000 1111) which is easy to understand as we care about 12 bits. But what would be the easiest way to create this mask programmatically? As I said it can be pretty random and sometimes we can span over three bytes (using 2 bits from first, then 8, and then 2 again from the last etc).

Or is there a better way to do this?

Edit: Added a bit more code to make the example easier to understand.

Comment: Where do you plan on defining your significant bits?

Comment: Oh I missed this but before I do this operation I map up the current data with "Start" and "Length" for every field. So this SetValue method are inside a class with those two properties.

So I have these three things:

- The whole binary string
- The start position of the wanted field
- The length of the wanted field

Comment: What is the actual purpose of the bit masks? Usually they are a collection of booleans, in which case a [Flags] enum is used..

Answer (score 2):

The main question here is actually... what *are* those bit fields? It's not very clear from your question where your data would come from and what it means.

See, generally, these bits will each represent a specific Boolean to enable and disable, so they should each have a specific *name*, too. The normal way this is represented is by using a [Flags] enum. They allow you to build up values where each bit flag is a named option you enable. There are loads of these already used in the .Net framework.

Basically, a flags enum is an enum that is defined as containing bits that can be combined. You just assign a name to each of the bits you use and combine them with OR operations.

```
[Flags]
public enum BitMask
{
    Empty = 0x00,    // 0000 0000 0000 0000
    BitOne = 0x01,   // 0000 0000 0000 0001
    BitTwo = 0x02,   // 0000 0000 0000 0010
    BitThree = 0x04, // 0000 0000 0000 0100
    BitFour = 0x08,  // 0000 0000 0000 1000
    BitFive = 0x10,  // 0000 0000 0001 0000
    BitSix = 0x20,   // 0000 0000 0010 0000
    BitSeven = 0x40, // 0000 0000 0100 0000
    BitEight = 0x80, // 0000 0000 1000 0000
    // etc...
}
```

You can even put commonly-used presets like `BitsFourAndFive  = 0x18` in there, which is pretty handy. Of course, your actual options should have the names of the booleans they actually represent.

Then you can combine your bits simply with

```
BitMask mask = BitMask.BitTwo | BitMask.BitFive | BitMask.BitEight;
```

I assume you know these, since you use them in your code, but anyway... to remove a bit from the mask, use an AND operation on the inverted value:

```
mask &= ~BitMask.BitTwo;
```

...and to check whether a bit is in the mask:

```
Boolean isTwo = (mask & BitMask.BitTwo) != 0;
```

And finally, to get your actual value... simply cast it to integer.

```
Int32 maskvalue = (Int32)mask;
```

The same can obviously be done the other way around too; if you have a value read from your input, you can just cast it to `BitMask`. A possible "is bit two enabled" check after reading a value:

```
Int32 readValue = ReadValue(); // wherever this comes from
Boolean isTwo = ((BitMask)readValue & BitMask.BitTwo) != 0;
```

Alternately, you can cast the `BitMask` enum entry to `Int32`; that works too.

Here's a real example from one of my projects that was used by a bunch of game sprite classes to both expose what kind of image they contained, and what kind of images they could use as input for saving as that sprite type:

```
[Flags]
public enum FileClass
{
    None = 0x00,
    Image1Bit = 0x01,
    Image4Bit = 0x02,
    Image8Bit = 0x04,
    ImageIndexed = 0x07,
    ImageHiCol = 0x08,
    Image = 0x0F,
}
```

As you see, for the save input data, I put the quick presets `Image` and `ImageIndexed` in there that combine multiple bits, to quickly indicate that the input either doesn't matter at all, or needs to be at least as low as 8-bit.

Answer (score 1):

You can take this code:

```
private static uint CreateBitMask( int start, int length )
{
     uint mask = 0xffffffff;
     mask >>= 32 - length;
     mask <<= start;
     return mask;
}
```

This creates a pattern of 'length' 1s, starting at the 'start' bit, where bit 0 is the least significant (written on the right end, if you write the bits on paper).

If you need more complex patterns, you can or them from multiple calls to `CreatePattern`:

```
uint bits = CreateBitMask( 2, 3 );
bits |= CreateBitMask( 3, 8 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to be able to specify the mask as a string. The least significant digit is on the right.
A usage example is:

```
uint mask = Helper.Bitmask("11000000_00000000_00000000_00000000");

Console.WriteLine(mask); // Displays 3221225472
```

Here is the static Helper class that does it:

```csharp
public static class Helper
{
    public static uint Bitmask(string mask)
    {
        // Strip formatting characters
        var sanitized = mask.Where(c => !"-_ .:".Contains(c));
        // Convert into bool array. Reverse it because BitArray reverses it.
        BitArray bitArr = new BitArray(sanitized.Select(c => c == '1' ? true : false).Reverse().ToArray());
        int len = (int)Math.Ceiling(bitArr.Count/32.0);     
        int[] array = new int[len];
        bitArr.CopyTo(array, 0);
        return (uint)array.First();
    }
}
```

As you see, it strips the input of all dashes, underscores, spaces, periods and colons, meaning you can use as many of those characters as you would like, in any way you like, to delimit or separate the bits for ease of reading.